# How to grab the input and output tensors after load a tf.saved_model in python

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Suppose I saved a model with following code

`tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, export_dir, in={'input_x': x, 'input_y':y}, out={'output_z':z})`

And now I load back the saved model in another python program as

`with tf.Session() as sess:
  tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ['serve'], export_dir)`

Now the question is how can I grab handles of the x, y, z tensors by the 'input_x', 'input_y', 'output_z' keys I specified in the input/output argument when call simple_save() method?

The only solution I found online relies on explicitly naming the x, y, z tensor when create them, and then use these names to retrieve them from graph, which seems to be quite redundant as we have specified keys for them in calling simple_save().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had exactly your problem and after some investigation (poor TF documentation in my opinion) i found the next solution:

Use the returned MetaGraphDef object to find your inputs \ outputs name mapping.

```
        graph = tf.Graph()
    with graph.as_default():
        metagraph = tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tag_constants.SERVING],save_path)

    inputs_mapping = dict(metagraph.signature_def['serving_default'].inputs)
    outputs_mapping = dict(metagraph.signature_def['serving_default'].outputs)
```

This code will give you the mapping between the names you supplied while saving to a "TensorInfo" object and from him you can easily get the mapped tensor name, for example:

```
    my_input = inputs_mapping['my_input_name'].name
    my_input_t = graph.get_tensor_by_name(my_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `tf.saved_model.loader.load` is a `MetaGraphDef` protocol buffer which should have all the signatures you set when saving your saved model; those should contain the names you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure whether your answer addressed my question. I was asking how to grab handle of the tensor by the keys I put in the signature. Maybe if you could put up some code, it will be more clear.